# Copy is not a member of System.IO.FileInfo in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, file, copy, directory, date-difference

I would like to know how do I copy files from one folder with less than 2days from todays date to another folder.

This is what I have:

```
Dim source As New DirectoryInfo("C:\Users\username\Desktop\123")
Dim target As New DirectoryInfo("C:\Users\username\Desktop\345")
Dim files = source.GetFiles("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Where(Function(file) file.LastWriteTime.Date.Equals(Date.Today.AddDays(-2)))
          For Each file As FileInfo In files
            file.copy(file.FullName, target.FullName & "\" & file.Name, True)
        Next file
```

**EDIT:**

Screenshot of error:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1st problem: In the For loop you are assigning a variable name `file` and that takes in conflict wth the `System.IO.File` Class that have the same name, so you need to change the variable name, of specify the Class of the `Copy` method.

2nd problem: The `Copy` method is a member of `System.IO.File` Class, not `System.IO.FileInfo` which are only a set of methods and properties to retrive file information, and in the For loop you are trying to acces the `Copy` member from a `FileInfo` object, but the member does not exist.

Then your code should be like this:

```
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Test() Handles MyBase.Load

        Dim Source As New DirectoryInfo("C:\Users\username\Desktop\123")
        Dim Target As New DirectoryInfo("C:\Users\username\Desktop\345")

        Dim Files As FileInfo() =
            (From [File] As FileInfo In Source.GetFiles("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
             Where [File].LastWriteTime.Date.Equals(Date.Today.AddDays(-2))).ToArray

        For Each [File] As FileInfo In Files
            IO.File.Copy([File].FullName, 
                         Path.Combine(Target.FullName, [File].Name), True)
        Next [File]

    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim source As New DirectoryInfo("C:\Users\username\Desktop\123")
Dim target As New DirectoryInfo("C:\Users\username\Desktop\345")
Dim ChildFile As FileInfo
For Each ChildFile In source.GetFiles("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Where(Function(file) file.LastWriteTime.Date.Equals(Date.Today.AddDays(-2)))
      ChildFile.CopyTo(Path.Combine(target.FullName, ChildFile.Name), False)
Next
```

Comment: @Codemunkeee- First thanks for your reply. After adding your code still it shows me the same error as shown in above screenshot..Can you say me why this error occurs ?

Comment: yes..without doing it how can I deal with such things :)

Comment: checked with the new code but the files are not copying to the dest directory.

Comment: No..not even now they're copying :(